# Windows 7 Licensing issue

Tags: windows-7, license

I bought a netbook that came with windows 7 starter and then bought the 7 professional. I upgraded my professional before authenticating my starter.

Right now, whenever windows 7 claims that my copy isn't genuine as it is not accepting both license keys.

I have so much data and stuff transferred to the netbook, that I was wondering if there is a simple solution to my situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give Microsoft a ring. They should be able to sort you out.

Comment: yup I'll call tomorrow morning and report back

Answer (score 0):

You may need to [work around](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/clean%5Finstall%5Fupgrade%5Fmedia.asp) the upgrade restrictions in this case. Method #2 worked for me when I had a similar problem.